# Error Column name or number of supplied values does not match

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

```
    string order_id;
    string order = "";
    string s, t;
    string[] a = new string[6];
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        con.Open();
        order = Request.QueryString["order"].ToString();
        if (order == Session["order_no"].ToString())
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "select * from UserTable where Username = '" + Session["user_name"].ToString() + "'";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                SqlCommand cmd1 = con.CreateCommand();
                cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd1.CommandText = "insert into Orders values ('" + dr["Username"].ToString() + "','" + dr["Email"].ToString() + "','" + dr["Address"].ToString() + "','" + dr["City"].ToString() + dr["State"].ToString() + "','" + dr["pincode"].ToString() + "','" + dr["PhoneNumber"].ToString() + "')";
                cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery(); }
```

This is the SQL for the 'Orders' table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Orders] (
[Id]          INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Username]    VARCHAR (50) NULL,
[Email]       VARCHAR (50) NULL,
[Address]     VARCHAR (50) NULL,
[City]        VARCHAR (50) NULL,
[State]       VARCHAR (50) NULL,
[pincode]     VARCHAR (50) NULL,
[PhoneNumber] VARCHAR (50) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC));
```

This is the SQL for 'UserTable'

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserTable] (
[Id]          INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Username]    VARCHAR (50) NULL,
[Email]       VARCHAR (50) NULL,
[Password]    VARCHAR (50) NULL,
[Address]     VARCHAR (50) NULL,
[City]        VARCHAR (50) NULL,
[State]       VARCHAR (50) NULL,
[pincode]     VARCHAR (50) NULL,
[PhoneNumber] VARCHAR (50) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC));
```

For some reason, I got an error saying that:

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

in the 'cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery' even though I have followed the values.

Comment: Is the Id row an auto incerement?

Comment: Oh dear oh dear. SQL injectable code running in a web application. Please please please use parameterised queries unless you want somebody to come and wipe your database using your website.

Comment: Your `Orders` table contains 8 columns, but your INSERT to `Orders` script only with 7 columns. Would suggest to mention which columns are needed in SQL. Example: `INSERT INTO Table1 (Col1, Col2 /*, Following columns if needed */) VALUES (@Value1, @Value2 /*, Following value based on mentioned columns */)`. Make sure that you provide the exact number of values based on mentioned columns needed.

Comment: Yeah, id is auto increment

Comment: **WARNING:** Your code is **dangerous**. It is wide open to SQL injection attacks. Always, *always, **always*** parametrise your code. [Why do we always prefer using parameters in SQL statements?](//stackoverflow.com/q/7505808)

Answer (score -1):

Please try with column names while inserting like below.

```
insert into table (column 1,column 2)
values (value 1, value 2);
```

Please check column name is equal to values

```
cmd1.CommandText = "insert into Orders(Username,Email,Address,City,State,pincode,PhoneNumber) values ('" + dr["Username"].ToString() + "','" + dr["Email"].ToString() + "','" + dr["Address"].ToString() + "','" + dr["City"].ToString() + "','" + dr["State"].ToString() + "','" + dr["pincode"].ToString() + "','" + dr["PhoneNumber"].ToString() + "')";
```

Recommended use with SP and pass parameters.

Comment: first of all, i want to thank you for your answer to my problem, but after using it, i encounter another problem in the same line. it says that 
'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'There are more columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause. The number of values in the VALUES clause must match the number of columns specified in the INSERT statement.'' is there any solution for it? thank you in advance.

Comment: between value city & state quotes are missing, i updated answer please check again

Comment: just done it and it is working, thank you so much

Comment: This leave a large injection issue in the OP's code; this needs to be parametrised. Otherwise this "solution" is just as dangerous as the OP's code.

Comment: @Larnu i already mentioned to pass parameter and use sp and i just provided a solution and inform him how to fix the error

Comment: Actually demonstrate how to parametrise, @samir . Also, where does the OP state that they identify as Male?